# Right Sidebar Scroll Conditionally

Tags: javascript, css

I have a sidebar which I want to scroll conditionally. I have provided the structure. In the layout both left and right side has lots of content. What I want when a user scroll down, let the both side scroll together. When the bottom of the right section comes visible, I want right section to stop going up, and let the left section keep scrolling. And when the user scrolls up, let the both left and right section scroll up. When the top edge of the right section comes visible, I want right section to stop scrolling anymore and let the left section keep scrolling on its own. How can I achieve this layout?

```css
.main{
  width : 100%;
}
.mainBody{
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background-color: pink;
  display : inline-block;
}
.mainBody div{
  margin-bottom : 500px;
}
.Sidebar{
  display : inline-block;
  width : 200px;
  float: right;
  background-color : yellow;
}
.Sidebar div{
  margin-bottom : 350px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main">
    <div class="mainBody">
      <div>Hello World 1</div>
      <div>Hello World 2</div>
      <div>Hello World 3</div>
      <div>Hello World 4</div>
      <div>Hello World 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Sidebar">
      <div>Sidebar Section 1</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 2</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 3</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 4</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet with javascript? I don't see anything yet but plain css/html setup

Comment: I haven't tried with Javascript. Can you show me how to do it with Javascript?

Comment: Can you share your java Script what you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried with javascript yet @RohitVerma

Answer (score 0):

First of all get the height of sidebar `$('#sidebar').height()` and decrease window height `$(window).height();` from sidebar height then you can apply/add fixed class `.fixed-right-bar`. Like given below example:-

```js
var sidebarHeight = $('#sidebar').height();
var documentHeight = $(window).height();
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > sidebarHeight-documentHeight){
 $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed-right-bar');
 }
 else{
 $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed-right-bar');
 }
});
```

```css
.main{
  width : 100%;
}
.mainBody{
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background-color: pink;
  display : inline-block;
}
.mainBody div{
  margin-bottom : 500px;
}
.Sidebar{
  display : inline-block;
  width : 200px;
  float: right;
  background-color : yellow;
}
.Sidebar div{
  margin-bottom : 350px;
}

.fixed-right-bar{ position:fixed; right:0; bottom:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="mainBody">
      <div>Hello World 1</div>
      <div>Hello World 2</div>
      <div>Hello World 3</div>
      <div>Hello World 4</div>
      <div>Hello World 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Sidebar" id="sidebar">
      <div>Sidebar Section 1</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 2</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 3</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 4</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean this ?

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  wh = $(this).height(),
  st = $(this).scrollTop(),
  side = $(".Sidebar"),
  sh = side.outerHeight();
  
  if( (st + wh) >= sh ) {
    side.addClass("fixed");
  } else {
    side.removeClass("fixed");
  }
})
```

```css
.main{
  width : 100%;
}
.mainBody{
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background-color: pink;
  display : inline-block;
}
.mainBody div{
  margin-bottom : 500px;
}
.Sidebar{
  display : inline-block;
  width : 200px;
  float: right;
  background-color : yellow;
}
.Sidebar div{
  margin-bottom : 350px;
}

.Sidebar.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="mainBody">
      <div>Hello World 1</div>
      <div>Hello World 2</div>
      <div>Hello World 3</div>
      <div>Hello World 4</div>
      <div>Hello World 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Sidebar">
      <div>Sidebar Section 1</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 2</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 3</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 4</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop scrolling right section when its reach bottom , you need to set `max-height` of `left` section to that `right` section `height` , also set overflow property ....

```js
var sidebarHeight = $('.Sidebar').height();

$(".mainBody").css({"max-height": sidebarHeight, "overflow-y":"scroll"});
```

```css
.main{
  width : 100%;
}
.mainBody{
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background-color: pink;
  display : inline-block;
}
.mainBody div{
  margin-bottom : 500px;
}
.Sidebar{
  display : inline-block;
  width : 200px;
  float: right;
  background-color : yellow;
}
.Sidebar div{
  margin-bottom : 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="mainBody">
      <div>Hello World 1</div>
      <div>Hello World 2</div>
      <div>Hello World 3</div>
      <div>Hello World 4</div>
      <div>Hello World 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Sidebar">
      <div>Sidebar Section 1</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 2</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 3</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 4</div>
      <div>Sidebar Section 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```